# Unable to catch global exceptions when using async/await in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, async-await

Adding snippets of the code so far

`app.module.ts`

```
@Injectable()
class UIErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  handleError(error) {
    super.handleError(error);
    alert(`Error occurred:${error.message}`);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    LoginModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useClass: UIErrorHandler,
    },
    AuthenticationService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
}
```

`LoginComponent` -> component declared in the `LoginModule`

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { AuthenticationService } from "~services/authentication.service";

@Component({
  selector: "login",
  templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./login.component.scss"],
})
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(public authenticationService: AuthenticationService, public router: Router) {
  }

  signIn = async () => {
    throw new Error("test error")
  };
}
```

If `async` is removed from the `signIn` function, the error is caught and everything works perfectly but with the `async` in place, the global handler fails to catch any exception. How do I go about catcing promise based exceptions globally?

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: test error
at LoginComponent.signIn (login.component.ts:56)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (LoginComponent.html:6)
at handleEvent (core.js:43993)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:45632)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:45247)
at dispatchEvent (core.js:29804)
at core.js:31837
at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:35379)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
```

Comment: Sounds more like you want to use a `HttpInterceptor`.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz haven't tried `HttpInterceptor` but in a scenario where a promise is used that is not a network call, how do I catch those errors?

Comment: try catch inside a async functions expects for a promise being rejected, if you are throwing directly without the corresponding 'await' there's no promise rejection there.

Also if you throw inside the try block in a async function, node it's going to complain you are not handling the exception.

Comment: @SebastiánEspinosa so given the above situation like in the example, how do I handle the error in a single place throughout my app rather than having catch blocks with logic everywhere to handle the error

Comment: @JudeFernandes I think you can't "raise" an error on a async context because there's no stack to raise to, if you want to handle all errors in the same place you can create a library to handle exceptions or use a event emiter to "raise" the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check [the stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1pm4tb?file=src/app/app.component.ts)? Is this the way you call the singIn function?

I have basically done the following:

Added the code in the component ts

```
export class AppComponent  {
    constructor() {
    this.signIn();
  }

  signIn = async () => {
    throw new Error('test error');
  }
}
```

Modified module.ts as follows:

```
@Injectable()
class UIErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  handleError(error) {
    super.handleError(error);
    alert(`Error occurred:${error.message}`);
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
    providers: [
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useClass: UIErrorHandler,
    }
  ],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This on itself, as you can see, works. Check you angular version [as there was an issue with non awaited promises in the past](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25612)

Comment: Thanks for the example and the detailed answer, the solution looks exactly like mine, I'm guessing there's something locally then that is interfering with the error, I will check it out, thanks